Having issues trying to add a new page/component to a angular system
Hi this is my first time doing maintence in a angular system and trying to build things on it and im trying to add a new page to the system to implement some bots on it that part its not that important but im having a hard time trying to do this new page [when i try to do the sudo ng build --configuration production it goes well untill i get a very very long list of errors ][1] that im not knowing how to treat cus no one has done changes except for this new component and the system is on the air right now, people are using it and no one is complaining so.....
im kinda in a dead end right i have checked the code from the component files again
bots.component.html  bots.component.scss  bots.component.spec.ts  bots.component.ts  bots.module.ts  bots-routing.module.ts
theese are the files inside the component
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/3QTq8AlD.png
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SYoNAI9m2V0IOKT9kg8CEteNydByTiVu/view?usp=sharing
i attatched a gdrive link to a file that contains the error log
i can share code too but if someone got any ideias on how to solve this

It's difficut help, but two ideas:

Error 8001: '...' it's not a know element: if '...'  is an Angular
component, then verify that ....
Say that you have forgot import the module where is declared the
component.
Try to explain. If you are not using standalone components, all the
components should be declared in a module and only in one module.
To use a component "children" inside a component "parent"

The two components are declared in the same module, the module have
(in the array `declarations`` if or "children" and "parent" share
the s, e.g. is
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [ChildrenComponent,ParentComponent, ..others components]
})
export class MyModule { }


Or the children is declared in a Module that export and import in
parent Module
//you have a ChildrenModule
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [ChildrenComponent,..others components],
  exports:[ChildrenComponent]
})
export class ChildrenModule { }
//And you have the myModule
@NgModule({
  imports: [ChildrenModule,...], //<--see you add the ChildrenModule
  declarations: [ParentComponent, ..others components]
})
export class MyModule { }




The errorTS255: Property '...' does not exist in html...
In the .html you only can use variables declares in .ts or template
reference variables. The template reference variables are "idicate"
in html that start with # and allow use any function or variable of
the component (or HTML tag).
e.g.
 <button (click)="childrenRef.doSomething()">do</button>
 <children #childrenRef>



